# Output not deleted entries in delete statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to output not deleted entries in delete statement?

For example, there is a Person table with the following data:

[image]

After executing the following statement:

```
delete Person where Id in (1, 3)
```

I need to output not deleted entries, for this case it's:

[image]

I tried to write with OUTPUT clause:

```
delete Person 
       output Id, Email
       where Id in (1, 3)
```

But I got the following error:

> Invalid column name 'Id' and 'Email'

Comment: You need to use delete and then select.

Comment: No - the output clause is directly related to the query with which it is used. If you delete rows, then the output clause will make those deleted rows available. There is no mechanism to output rows that are not affected by the statement. And please have a look at the documentation to correct your syntax (though it doesn't do what you want).

Comment: ... and when the table in question happens to contain some several billion records, and you are deleting just 2, you are going to receive all the remaining ones in such an output, am I correct?

Comment: @Piotr I need to use only delete statement.

Comment: @SMor Thank you for the response. Indeed, unfortunately, there is no such mechanism.

Comment: @RogerWolf Yes, you're.

Comment: Please add to your question why need to use only delete statement. Delete will access only rows matching WHERE clause, so doing it in one statement looks impossible and it is  easy to do with separate select.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete Person where Id in (1, 3);
select id, email from Person;
```